# What happens to pressure when a liquid turns into a gas in a confined chamber?

Tags: pressure, ideal-gas, volume

I'm doing an experiment requiring immense pressures. Since I do not have access to a pump that can create these pressures I settled on something different...

Instead of using a pump I want to utilize the expansion ratio from liquid to gas of a particular element; liquid Neon. Neon has the [highest expansion ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_ratio) of all known substances, by a factor of 1:1445!

I was wondering, if I put liquid Neon in a container with a given volume, seal it, and then heat it above Neon's boiling point (not very hard as [Neon's boiling point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon) is 27.104 K) what would happen to the pressure once the Neon has expanded by a factor of 1:1445? How much liquid Neon would I need to achieve a certain pressure with a container of a given volume? Would the increased pressures have any effect on the boiling point of the Neon?

I'm assuming the ideal gas laws apply, but if they don't let me know!

Comment: ideal gas laws do not apply when the density of the gas is approximately the same as the density of its liquid form. You need a more complicated relationship called an *equation of state* for that substance, which applies where the ideal gas law does not. All equations of state are approximations that work well in certain ranges of temperature and pressure, so care has to be applied when choosing which one to use..

Comment: BTW if you are working with pressures that great, what sort of container do you intend to use for confining the neon?

Comment: I don't know about "expansion ratio," but if your plan is to pressurize a vessel by sealing a liquified substance inside, then the the most relevant property of the substance probably would be its _[vapor pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_pressure)_

Comment: last comment: you should be able to find something called a phase diagram for neon on the web, which tells you how neon behaves at a variety of different pressures and temperatures. Do you have one in hand?

Comment: Re, "...once the Neon has expanded by a factor of 1:1445?..." OK, Wikipedia says that _[expansion ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_ratio)_ is the ratio of volume of some amount of cryogenic liquid _at amospheric pressure_, and the volume of the same amount of gaseous substance at room temperature and _at amospheric pressure_. If your goal is to achieve "immense pressure," then it's not going to expand all that much.

Comment: @SteveMucci, the ideal gas law will not work for your application.  Are you able to provide more details on what you are trying to do?  What temperature and pressure does your experiment need?  Can your container withstand this pressure?  How do you plan on controlling the pressure at a specified setpoint?  There is a lot of process engineering involved in a good answer, and a lot more data is needed.

Comment: Ok I want to answer all of your questions and concerns. @nielsnielsen, I'll check out the "equation of state", but I'm more interested in the phase diagram you spoke of in your third comment. For the container I plan on bending a significantly strong tube of metal and weld the gap into a torus. And David I am simply testing the hypothesis that a sufficiently strong container can contain immense pressures induced by the expansion of liquid Neon within said container.

Comment: Alright, [here is the phase diagram for Neon](https://goo.gl/images/8DjAen). In my experiment the container will be cryogenically cooled to about 150 K under operating conditions, but otherwise will be between 150 K and standard temperature.

Comment: The phase diagram shows that Neon would be supercritical for these operating temperatures and presssures, not a gas, not a liquid. Does the supercritical Neon still have an expansion ratio sufficient enough to cause an increase in pressure during operation?

Answer (score 1):

The gas would not expand 1445 times unless you use a small amount in a large vessel.  If it is a sealed vessel, the pressure would increase until it reached max pressure of the vessel or it reached equilibrium.

I work with anhydrous ammonia on a regular basis.  I will talk about the pressure and temperature of ammonia as it is what I am most familiar with.

One of the worst things you can do is trap liquid ammonia in a pipe.
-28F it would be at 0 psi
0F - 16 psi

32F - 48 psi

60F - 93 psi

100F - 200 psi

With ammonia, you only fill a tank part of the way to allow the gas to flash and stabilize.

To do your experiment, you are going to need safety relief valves, a lot of specialized equipment.   What you are proposing is very dangerous.

Your vessel has to be rated for 40% more pressure than you expect to achieve. Unless you are using very small amounts, this is not something you can piece together yourself.  You are going to need a way to fill the vessel, and then remove the liquid when you are done.   You are going to need a way to add the neon without heating it up too much.

[image: Ammonia Pressure Vessel]
[image: Sample Fill Tank]

Answer (score 0):

Boiling point is a function of pressure.

As the pressure goes up, so does the boiling point (for most materials)

You should find a phase diagram for neon, and look at the line between gas and liquid. That will tell you what temperature you need to reach your desired pressure.

Comment: *"Boiling point is a few nation of pressure."* That sentence really doesn't rock...

Comment: Sorry, I plead autocorrect. Thanks for pointing it out.